# learn python the hard way exercise 26 trouble

Tags: python

I am doing exercise 26 in learn python the hard way and have been struggling on it. I have read it backwards and everything, but in line 77 I get :

```
sentence = "All god \t things come to those who weight."
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I dont know why the arrow is at the e .
I dont just want to know how to fix it but what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably missing a close bracket, brace, or parenthesis on the previous line of code.

**Edit:** From the code:

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_pont
```

There is no close parenthesis at the end of the line.

This is **almost always** the problem if you have a `SyntaxError` near the beginning of a line that looks right.

Answer (score 3):

The original statement is

```
sentence = "All god\tthings come to those who weight."
```

Make sure you typed it properly.

It's also possible that the code before this line is messed up.

EDIT: I checked the source, and it is broken: http://learnpythonthehardway.org/exercise26.txt

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_pont
```

The open parenthesis was not closed.

Comment: @agf The preceding line has an unclosed paren expression. Paren expressions can extend across lines, indentation laws being lifted. So the Python parser carries on with the expression started with ``(start_pont``, picking tokens from the next line. I'm not sure, but I think the juxtaposed variable name ``sentence`` is already the syntax violation.

Comment: @ThomasH I know that. Foo Bah's original answer just said "You didn't type the line in exactly the same", when the problem was actually on the previous line. After I pointed out that typing some extra spaces in the string wouldn't give a syntax error, then he added the correct solution.

Comment: NB: Exercise 26 of LPTHW is about fixing a broken program text, s. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex26.html. So don't be surprised that it is broken :).

Comment: @agf That's the curse on SO: Edits can make comments weird :).

Comment: Yeah. Most of the time I delete comments like that once the problem is fixed, but I forgot to. Now I can't unless you delete your comments too because it will make you look nuts :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes in the exercise26.txt

One of them is line 74 has a parenthesis that isn't closed:

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_pont
```

should be

```
print "We'd have %d beans, %d jars, and %d crabapples." % secret_formula(start_pont)
```

(and probably start_point as start_pont isn't defined).

Syntax errors are usually on the line or the line above.

Comment: Don't solve the whole thing for him! That completely defeats the point!

Comment: I edited out the complete answer. What if other people come here for help on that exercise? You don't want them to see the whole answer when they only want a small piece, it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @Shameer's been stuck on this problem enough to ask for help.  Sometimes seeing what are the corrections needed, may allow him to pin down his misunderstanding.  If other people came here for help on the exercise -- they are already admitted defeat.  Sometimes you have to admit defeat after trying very hard and see what the answer is.  Ideally you'll try to solve it yourself; and when you can't you see the solution and learn from it.

Comment: But he didn't ask for the solution to the whole thing. He just asked for help with one particular part.

Comment: This is good but i didn't really want it solved for me i would be good with "Syntax errors are usually on the line or the line above.
"